# There exists a positive and differentiable function $ f(x) $ such that $ f(x) \cdot (e^x + \left|x\right|) $ is differentiable in $ \mathbb{R} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I need to prove or disprove the following statement:

There exists a positive and differentiable function $ f(x) $ such that $ f(x) \cdot (e^x + \left|x\right|) $ is differentiable in $ \mathbb{R} $.

Is my proof correct?

The statement is false.

Suppose. to the contrary, that there exists a positive and differentiable function $ f(x) $ on $ \mathbb{R} $ such that $ f(x) * (e^x + \left|x\right|) $ is differentiable in $ \mathbb{R} $. $ \forall x, f(x) > 0 $, which means $ \frac{1}{f(x)} $ is well-defined and differentiable. Therefore, as the product of two differentiable functions, $\frac{f(x)\cdot (e^x + \left|x\right|)}{f(x)} \Rightarrow (e^x + |x|)$ is differentiable at $ x = 0 \Rightarrow e^x + |x| - e^x $ is differentiable at $ 0 \Rightarrow |x| $ is differentiable at $ 0 $ - contradiction.

Comment: Neat argument. It is very clear.

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct.

Comment: You can as well subtract $f(x)e^x$ first, and then divide by $f(x).$